# Overflow in ASP Classic

Tags: asp-classic, overflow

I was wondering if someone could help me, as I have gone blind to what I believe is a simple cause to a simple error.

I have this code:

```
 doRound1(x1)
  denom1 = 5
  y1 = denom1 - x1 mod denom1
  if y1 <> denom1 then
    x1= x1+y1
  end if

  doRound1=x1
 End function

 'theCalc = 20488888888.684
  theCalc = cDbl(11111111111) * 1.844
  doRound1(theCalc)
```

I get this error

```
Microsoft VBScript runtime  error '800a0006'
Overflow: 'x1'
```

Caused by this line in the above code:

```
 y1 = denom1 - x1 mod denom1
```

Any ideas? As I say, I have gone blind this p.m.

Comment: Could it be that x1 is a vaule too large for an Int/Long?

Answer (score 4):

The answer appears to be at [PRB: "Overflow" with Integer Division and MOD Operator](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/205053):

> The Visual Basic Help topic for the
>   Mod operator and the integer division
>   operator () explains that if floating
>   point numbers are used in the
>   expression, they are converted to
>   Longs first. Thus, if the floating
>   point number is greater than the
>   maximum value of a Long
>   (2,147,483,647), or less than the
>   minimum value for a long
>   (-2,147,483,648), an overflow error
>   will occur.

The answer is available there as well:

> The following code demonstrates how to
>   perform integer division and modulo
>   arithmetic when the size of an operand
>   is sufficiently large to cause
>   overflow:

```
Dim dblX as Double
Dim dblY as Double
dblX = 2147483648                ' numerator
dblY = 123                       ' denominator

' round off the numerator and denominator (ensure number is .0)
dblX = INT(dblX + .5)         
dblY = INT(dblY + .5)      

' Emulate integer division
MsgBox FIX(dblX / dblY)             
' Emulate modulo arithmetic
MsgBox dblX - ( dblY * FIX(dblX / dblY) )
```

Comment: Any reason Int(x + .5) is used instead of CInt(x) ?

Comment: Also it would be better to edit the code to VBScript since this is a classic ASP question not a VB6 question.  +1 though

Answer (score 1):

I believe that when you don't specifically define the values, ASP Classic assumes a numeric value to be an int (which is only 32767).  Try forcing your values to be longs

```
 Function doRound1(x1)
  x1 = CDbl(x1)
  denom1 = CDbl(5)
  y1 = denom1 - x1 mod denom1
  if y1 <> denom1 then
    x1= x1+y1
  end if

  doRound1=x1
 End function
```

**Note**: I haven't actually tested this.

Comment: The answer on this one (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/316312/misunderstanding-of-long-data-type-in-vba ) goes into a bit more detail about this.

Comment: @C. Ross: x1 = CLng(x1) causes `Overflow: 'cLng'`

Comment: Actually, those should probably be Doubles. However, I suspect that you have the right answer otherwise. I recommend doubles because a Long in VBScript still caps at 2B; also OP's input appears to be a double based on the comments in the post.

Comment: @John: Still doesn't help the OP. `theCalc = 20488888888.684` then `cDbl(theCalc) mod cDbl(5)` still causes `Overflow: 'cDbl(...)'`

Comment: VBScript has its limitations ... but yes, CDbl makes more sense.

Comment: @C. Ross: -1. This untested sample doesn't work. The correct answer is that `mod` causes floating point numbers used in the expression to be converted to Longs first. If the floating point number is too big to fit in a Long, an overflow will occur.